# Добавление нового заказа в высоконагруженную систему

Tags: mysql

необходима помощь с высоконагруженным запросом.

Необходимо составить SQL-запрос, который позволяет заносить данные заказа клиента с учетом специфики высоконагруженной системы.

При составлении SQL-запроса необходимо учесть следующее:

- для занесения данных в корзину заказа (shopping_cart) необходимы значения внешних ключей (fk_order и fk_product);
- существует проблема получения значения id_order, в случае занесения данных заказа в таблицу Order. Она обусловлена ​​тем, что за время от занесения данных заказа до наполнения корзины, в высоконагруженной системе уже могли быть оформлены другие заказы;
- существует проблема добавления товаров (fk_product) в корзину заказа (shopping_cart). Перед добавлением товара в корзину, необходимо проверить, превышает ли количество (shop_quantity) заказанного товара в корзине его количество (quantity) на складе. Если нет, то количество товара на складе необходимо уменьшить на количество в корзине. Однако, за время наполнения корзины в высоконагруженной системе уже могли быть оформлены другие заказы на этот товар. То есть текущее значение количества товара в корзине и на складе (shop_quantity и quantity) может оказаться не актуальным (недействительным).

**Таблица "Order":**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MyDB_Inno_DB`.`Order`(
`id_order` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fk_client` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`fk_delivery` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
`date` DATE NOT NULL,
`st_initiate` BIT(1) NOT NULL,
`st_executed` BIT(1) NOT NULL,
`address` TEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL,
`delivery_price` FLOAT(6,2) NULL,
`delivery_date` DATE NULL,
`delivery_time` VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL,
`delivery_phone` VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_order`),
INDEX `fk_Order_Client_id_name` (`fk_client` ASC),
INDEX `fk_Order_Delivery_id_name` (`fk_delivery` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_Client_name` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_client`)
REFERENCES `MyDB_InnoDB`.`Client` (`id_client`)
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_Delivery_name` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_delivery`)
REFERENCES `MyDB_InnoDB`.`Delivery` (`id_delivery`)
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Таблица "Shopping_Cart":**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MyDB_InnoDB`.`Shopping_Cart`(
`fk_order` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`fk_product` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`shop_quantity` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`fk_order`, `fk_product`),
INDEX `fk_Shopping_Cart_Order_id_name` (`fk_order` ASC),
INDEX `fk_Shopping_Cart_Products_id_name` (`fk_product` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_Shopping_Cart_Order_name` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_order`)
REFERENCES `MyDB_InnoDB`.`Order` (`id_order`)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Shopping_Cart_Products_name` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_product`)
REFERENCES `MyDB_InnoDB`.`Products` (`id_product`)
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci
```

**Таблица "Products":**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MyDB_InnoDB`.`Products`(
`id_product` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fk_catalog` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`product_name` VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
`release_date` DATE NOT NULL,
`price` FLOAT(6,2) NOT NULL,
`quantity` INT NOT NULL,
`description` TEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_product`),
INDEX `fk_Products_Catalog_id_name` (`fk_catalog` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_Products_Catalog_name` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_catalog`)
REFERENCES `MyDB_InnoDB`.`Catalog` (`id_catalog`)
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Как я это понимаю:**

1) сначала добавляется запись о новом заказе в таблицу "Order" (id_order, fk_client, date);

2) далее идёт заполнение корзины, таблица "Shopping_Cart" (fk_order, fk_product, shop_quantity), также перед добавлением товара мы проверяем условия: превышает ли количество (shop_quantity) заказанного товара в корзине его количество (quantity) на складе и если нет, то количество товара на складе необходимо уменьшить на количество в корзине.

При этом не понятно как в одном запросе произвести вставку сразу в 2 таблицы (Order, Shopping_Cart) и как выполнить следующие условия:

1) При этом существует проблема получения значения id_order, в случае занесения данных заказа в таблицу Order. Она обусловлена ​​тем, что за время от занесения данных заказа до наполнения корзины, в высоконагруженной системе уже могли быть оформлены другие заказы.

2) Однако, за время наполнения корзины в высоконагруженной системе уже могли быть оформлены другие заказы на этот товар. То есть текущее значение количества товара в корзине и на складе (shop_quantity и quantity) может оказаться не актуальным (недействительным).

Comment: Не понимаю, какая вообще проблема с id_order и зачем запись в таблицу заказов заносить одновременно с корзиной. Это вообще отдельные операции. Создаем заказ, при этом получаем last_insert_id() т.е. id добавленной записи, далее спокойно используем его везде, где необходимо, корзину можно пополнять хоть на следующий день.

Comment: дак вы же не получаете id созданного заказа, как максимальный id из таблицы?

Comment: Что касается продуктов и корзины, если не брать во внимание, что БД спроектирована не верно и количество оставшегося товара не должно находиться в таблице продуктов, то все просто. В одной транзакции читаем нужный продукт с for update, проверяем количество, если достаточно, создаем запись в корзине, вычитаем из продукта, фиксируем транзакцию

Comment: Если вдруг заказ создается единоразово сразу со всей корзиной (что очень странно), то просто все действия, начиная с создания заказа делаем в единой транзакции. проблемы id заказа опять же не существует, она у нас в переменной все время действия процедуры. При любой ошибке, типа недостачи товара, откатываем всю транзакцию

Comment: @Mike Здравствуйте, спасибо за помощь. С транзакцией создание заказа единоразово сразу со всей корзиной реализуется идеально, но мне необходимо это реализовать с помощью триггера. Я так полагаю, что единственный выход с триггером - это создать AFTER INSERT TRIGGER для таблицы Order, в теле которого будет операция вставки в корзину, но проблема в том, что тогда нужно постоянно изменять значения fk_product и shop_quantity внутри триггера. Или возможно есть ещё какой-то способ это реализовать используя триггеры?

Comment: А откуда в триггере на Order возьмутся данные для корзины ? В тиггере не доступна никакая информация, кроме вставляемой в текущую таблицу

Comment: `DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER store_myisam.InsertShopping_Cart
    AFTER INSERT
    ON store_myisam.order
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    insert into store_myisam.shopping_cart (fk_order, fk_product, shop_quantity) values (new.id_order, '4001', '10');
    END $$
    DELIMITER ;`

Comment: @Mike В этом и проблема. Я выше привел код триггера, в нем указываются данные для корзины, но я понимаю, что так не делается. Похоже кроме как в транзакции - одновременную вставку никак не реализовать.

Comment: Не понятно зачем вообще нужен триггер. Зачем пытаться решить задачу не предназначенными для этого средствами

Comment: @Mike Я прекрасно понимаю, что триггер абсолютно не нужен в данном случае, но для курсовой работы необходимы именно высоконагруженные триггеры. А транзакции мы ещё не проходили по предмету, поэтому вот такое ограничение. Спасибо, за помощь и что потратили своё время. Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Тут триггерами можно делать только одно, при изменении Cart автоматом менять количество в Products. И в принципе этого достаточно, если не ставить себе странную цель писать весь заказ с корзиной целиком.